# Regression for multiple data points and multiple years

Tags: regression, time-series

I'm fairly new to regression analysis, but I am planning on writing an economics paper involving revenues and standings for a sports league - specifically, I want to determine whether a team's standing at the end of the season is correlated with their revenue. Obviously, I could run a simple regression for all the teams in the league for one season, but one season is really just "one" data point - I want to test this over multiple seasons, say 20 years. Is a time series approach the best thing to do here? If not, what is the best method i should use?

Comment: Have you looked into/googled mixed models aka random effects models? That might be a good start for analysis longitudinal data.

Comment: Mixed models include both random and fixed effects.